# Error while finding the largest number from a list

Tags: c#, loops, input, max, do-while

I'm trying to solve a problem where you add random number from the keyboard and when you type "0" it stops and shows the largest number.
This is what I did:

```
        int max = 0;
        Console.WriteLine();
        String input = Console.ReadLine();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (n > max)
                max = n;
        }

        while (!input.ToLower().Equals("0"));



        Console.WriteLine(max);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I keep getting ": 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" and I don't know why. I'm not expecting any other result than an int.

Comment: 1) you never update your `input` variable no matter how many times you read the data 2) you never check for `0` (to satisfy _"when you type "0" it stops and shows the largest number"_ condition), for some reason you check for `x` 3) if `x` is a stop sign, what would happen if user enters it as firs input?

Comment: You may find the [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) method helpful. The `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception if the `string` is not a valid `int` value.

Comment: My bad - I typed x by mistake when I added the question. But it was "0" when I did it.

Comment: You can remove the `.ToLower()` since `"0".ToLower() == "0"`